# pyqtgraph ignores some of my data and add some random data

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I am using `pyqt4` and `PlotWidget` for viewing some plots.

I have some `datetime` values in y-axis data. but the problem is that `pyqtgraph` ignores some of datetime values and add some random data into them.

I used `setRange` method but because some specific data may exists between **min** and **max** datetime values i don't think this method could be helpful.

How can I draw pilots with exactly my own data?

this is normal zoom that some points do not have datetime
[image]

and this is zoomed plot that a point do not have datetime in y-axis and on the other hand `2015-06-08 20:43:20` does not exists in my data that automatically added by `pyqtgraph`
[image]

and here is the code that generate above plots

```
class DateTimeAxis(pg.AxisItem):
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        ret_dts = []
        for x in values:
            ret_dts.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
        return ret_dts

axis = DateTimeAxis(orientation='bottom')
plotw = PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': axis})
times = [1433685535, 1433771935, 1433782735, 1433800735, 1433858335]
ydata = [10, 15, 25, 40, 30]
plotw.plot(y=ydata,x=times)
```

Comment: Could you provide some example code that display the behaviour you are observing? It doesn't have to be the full code nor the full data, just a stripped down version that we can use to understand the problem and check whether we have solved it. Currently your question ought to be closed because you didn't provide nearly enough information to understand the issue.

Comment: In addition to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please include a screenshot showing the erroneous graph.

Comment: please add photos in question because i dont have enough reputations.

Comment: Thank you for providing images, I've edited them in the question for you. Could you now provide the MCVE as requested above? (a minimal example that can be used to reproduce these plots)

Comment: @Bartanix Thankyou for including a code sample, but that sample is not a **complete** piece of code (see the link above on how to make an MCVE). The main issue with it is that you haven't provided the contents of `times_dict` and `data_dict` which makes it impossible to reproduce the problem. **Please create and include a small example which includes everything needed to reproduce the problem.**

Comment: @three_pineapples sample data added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AxisItem` is not designed to do what you want. It has no knowledge of the data in your plot; it only knows the min/max values along the axis. You will need to either call `AxisItem.setTicks()` or override `AxisItem.tickValues()` to display the actual values of your data.

Comment: i used `datetime.utcfromtimestamp` and no change happend to shape of plot and still some points do not have datetimes. could you please send me a photo of your plot? is everything ok with datetimes? extra random datetimes? missing datetimes? did you run exactly my code?

Comment: The position of the data points in the plot appears to be correct (try plotting with `symbol='o'` to see exactly where the point are). Maybe you are concerned about the position of the axis ticks at the bottom? These do not (and should not) correspond exactly to the points in your data; they are simply chosen to fill the available space along the axis.

Comment: i do not care if some random data added to y-axis data but i want my y-axis data (the data those related to the x-axis) appears in y-axis. did you see that in your plot?

Comment: I don't really understand. Do you mean that you want 15 to be displayed on the y axis because it is a value that appears in your data? Do you mean that you want the exact time of each data point to be represented by a tick on the x axis?

Comment: i'm sorry. wrongly i said y-axis instead of x-axis. i want all datetime  values in the list appears in x-axis

Comment: `setTicks` worked well. sorry i do not have enough reputations for vote up. thank you